# Сложный sql-запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица, куда записываются выплаты. Структура такая:

```
bill_id|owner_id|bill_first_name
owner_id - ID продавца
bill_first_name - имя клиента
```

Для того, чтобы выбрать все выплаты текущего продавца, можно просто:

```
SELECT * FROM bills AS bill WHERE bill.owner_id=5 GROUP BY bill.bill_first_name
```

Для того, чтобы получить количество уникальных `bill_first_name` для каждого `owner_id`, нужно нечто похожее на

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM bills AS bill WHERE bill.owner_id=58 GROUP BY bill.bill_first_name
```

Но получается где-то так:

```
1  
4  
5  
5
```

Как мне получить количество записей после такого запроса (не сумму!), в данном случае 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему Ваше GROUP BY здесь не нужен.

Select count(distinct bill_first_name) from  bills were owner_id=58);

Тоже давно это было, но помнится, что count(distinct... )- было допустимо.

Answer (score 1):

давно с мускулом не баловался, но может что-то типо этого:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM bills AS bill WHERE bill.owner_id=58 GROUP BY bill.bill_first_name)
```